# Why do I have this laravel error?

Tags: php, laravel, compiler-errors, routes, frameworks

Everything was working fine but then I deleted the history of the browser (Chrome Versión 55.0.2883.87 m) and suddenly my Laravel (5.3 version) project stoped working.
It works fine when I go to the index of my project, but when I click on any of the links I have the following error:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

1/1
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 766
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 621
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: Apparently you did remove those pages, and they only *appeared* to be working because they were in the HTML cache of the browser. Check your defined routes.

Comment: The routes are ok. As I said before, everything was working fine, but as soon as I deleted the cache of the broweser every link shows that error.

Answer (score 0):

These errors are found when you are visiting a page or link which is not registered in the routes.

Please check your routes.
You can edit this page inside `\resources\views\errors`. Default, there will not be a file `404.blade.php`, you can create one and edt that page as you want

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it. I just executed Ccleaner and my routes are working again, but thanks for your comments, guys.